# How to show a Scanned Image of a Fingerprint in Asp.net application

Tags: c#

I am creating a website which intends to read a finger print from a finger print scanner, and then display it in my application as an image .
SO far I have found no help against this requirement .

Answer (score 2):

Bio-metric scanners typically have their own API. Reading hardware APIs from a website is most likely not possible. You typically need native code running on the hardware to access this functionality.

I certainly don't want any websites reading from my scanner. There are plugins which allow a browser to access the scanner, but that is also native code running on the hardware.

EDIT:
ActiveX/Java applet would be a solution according the [Digital Persona SDK](http://www.digitalpersona.com/Developer-Tools/SDKs/U-are-U-SDK-for-Windows/).

Comment: I can imagine the SDK to come with an example of using the device from a browser on the client machine, for example using a browser extension or Flash/Silverlight object. OP should read the documentation.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, RTFM is a much needed skill here. Updated my answer though to reflect the plugin route. Not how I would proceed but I don't know the requirements or who is making the requirements either :)